# Phrase for someone who worked for one company but now works for a competitor

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In Italian we have a sentence,

> passare alla concorrenza

It means that someone who worked for company X starts working with company Y, who is a competitor of X (they sell the same goods for the same market). This sentence can also mean that, say, a TV host starts hosting shows on another TV channel, etc.

Can you help me find an English collocation with the same meaning, if any exists?

Comment: He defected to the competition. [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/changed%20sides)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say *Bob* first worked for Uber, but now he works for Lyft, their competitor.

*Work for the competition* seems clear to me in this context. Using Bob as the example,

> I'm disappointed in Bob. I heard he's *working for the competition* now.

Here's just one example usage I found online:

> [Sleeping With The Enemy: Tech Employees Who Go To Work For The Competition](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kevinmurnane/2017/02/02/sleeping-with-the-enemy-tech-employees-who-go-to-work-for-the-competition/#589bb4fb2451)

As for an idiom, how about *jump ship*?

> [jump ship](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/jump-ship)
>   a) to leave an organization that you are working for, especially in order to join another
>   *The best employees jumped ship at the first opportunity.*
>   (Longman)

Using Bob as an example,

> After all those recent scandals, Bob jumped ship and now he works for Lyft.

Comment: As far as I know it includes doing so suddenly.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could it is often used in that way, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

There is an idiom that fits:

> Now she's playing for the other side.

That is, she is playing for a rival or competitor.

Comment: A link to this idiom would help.

Comment: Would help you do what? Don't you know how to use Google?

Answer (score 0):

This idiom is used where I live. This happened this year, where I work and someone went to work for the competition or the enemy.

> He is now working for the **enemy**!

Some define enemy simply as not a friend.

> Enemy (n.)
>
> Look up enemy at Dictionary. comearly 13c., "one hateful toward and intent on harming (someone)," from Old French enemi (12c., Modern French ennemi), earlier inimi (9c.) "enemy, adversary, foe; demon, the Devil," from Latin inimicus "an enemy," literally "an unfriend," noun use of adjective meaning "hostile, unfriendly" (source also of Italian nemico, Catalan enamic, Spanish enemigo, Portuguese inimigo), from **in- "not" (see in- (1)) + amicus "friend"** related to amare "to love" . From c. 1300 in English as "adversary of God, unbeliever, heathen, anti-Christian;" late 14c. as "the Devil;" also late 14c. as "member of an armed, hostile body in a war, feud, etc.;" of the opposing military forces as a whole, from c. 1600. From mid-14c. as an adjective. - [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=enemy)

Even Trump has used a similar phrase about the democrats (or if you wish the competitors) as seen in this article: [Trump embraces ‘enemy of the people,’ a phrase with a fraught history.](https://www.bostonglobe.com/news/nation/2017/02/26/trump-embraces-enemy-people-phrase-with-fraught-history/XL3VWjgX3rxkRiP3X95YCN/story.html)

Answer (score -1):

"[turncoat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turncoat)" might be the word you are looking for if you mention betrayal.

"[Rat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rat)" might be the word if you prefer something rather informal and insulting for a person who changes loyalty.

["change sides"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/change+sides) can also be what you are looking for.

Comment: I think the word "turncoat" is different as it means somebody whose "loyalty" is given to the other side. Hence, betrayal is involved. I don't think there would be outright 'betrayal' if a person works for a competitor (but there are 'ethical' issues). In the first place, companies usually do not allow that (until x year(s) lapsed). But I may be wrong, so let's just wait for other answers? (not my downvote, btw)

Comment: Companies can't just "not allow that." Many companies do have employees (and contractors) sign a non-compete contract, with typical terms ranging from a year to maybe five years, although five years is a long time to prohibit somebody from working in their career field and everything is negotiable, and depending on circumstances the non-compete may or may not be enforceable.